# AttributeError: type object 'challee' has no attribute 'display'

Tags: python

I keep getting this error when am using python version 3.3.2, i am not making anything i was watching a tutorial on youtube and tried it, but the version he was using is 2.7

```
>>> class challee:
def cname(self,name):
    self.name = name
    def display(self):
        return self.name
    def say(self):
        print("help %s" % self.name)


>>> challee
<class '__main__.challee'>
>>> first = challee
>>> second = challee
>>> first.cname(first,"becky")
>>> second.cname(first,"tony")
>>> first.display()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    first.display()
AttributeError: type object 'challee' has no attribute 'display'
```

Comment: Perhaps the indentation issue. Your two methods are probably treated as local the the method `cname()`.

Comment: Unrelated to the indentation issue, your code has another bug. You need to create instances of `challee` instead of using the class for everything. (Python 2.7 would have caught this, but a simplification in the 3.x line removed that check.)

Comment: your right it is the indent issue, i indented too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indented the `display` and `say` methods too far; they are nested functions *inside* of the `challee` class.

Note that you are never making instances; you are instead creating multiple references to the class. *Call** the class to produce an instance:

```
first = challee()
second = challee()
```

and then you don't have to pass in an explicit argument for `self` either:

```
first.cname('becky')
```

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks it was the indent issue, i had to use a explicit argument for self in order for the first.display to show 'becky'

Answer (score 0):

If you call a method on an instance, as in Martijn's example, the `self` argument gets added automatically for you at call time.  So, for your class:

```
class challee:
    def cname(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def display(self):
        return self.name
    def say(self):
        print("help %s" % self.name)
```

you'd need to make an instance of the class and then call your methods against that, like he demonstrated:

```
a = challee()
a.cname('Becky')
```

Since this invisibly passes the instance in as the `self` argument, it is equivalent to calling the method against the class (which does not implicitly pass anything as `self`) and passing in the instance by hand:

```
a = challee()
challee.cname(a, 'Becky')
```

The problem is that it's an error to pass in a class as `self`, it must be an instance.

You can create a function that doesn't need an instance to operate, by using the `@staticmethod` decorator:

```
class challee:
    @staticmethod
    def say(whatever):
        print(whatever)
```

If you define a method in this way, self isn't required as an argument at all, and you'd call the function like this:

```
challee.say("this is a test")
```

or like this:

```
a = challee()
a.say("this is a test")
```

However, those two calls would do the same thing.